# Target Unreachable, identifier 'regionMaster' resolved to null

Tags: jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I created a managedBean & .xhtml page.It works fine on jsf 2.1 but not working on jsf 2.2 .Showing error Target Unreachable, identifier 'regionMaster' resolved to null

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:prime="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<head>
</head>
<ui:composition>
    <h:form id="regionMaster" name="regionMaster">
        <div id="region">
             <table align="center">
                 <tr>
                    <td><prime:panel header="Region">
                    <prime:messages autoUpdate="true" />
                    <prime:panelGrid style="margin-top:20px">
                        <prime:row>
                            <prime:column>
                                <h:outputLabel  for="txtRegionID" value="RegionID" />
                            </prime:column>
                            <prime:column colspan="3">
                                <prime:inputText id="txtRegionID" value="#{regionMaster.regionId}"
                                    label="Region ID" required="true" />
                            </prime:column>

                            <prime:column>
                                <!--    <h:commandButton id="openPopUp" value="..."
                                target="RegionList.xhtml"
                                onclick="window.open('RegionList.xhtml','childWindow','status=no,toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no,resizable = no,width=1008,height=390,scrollbars,left=100,top=50');"
                                action="#{regionList.xhtml}" />-->

                                <!--  <prime:commandButton value="View" icon="ui-icon-extlink"
                                actionListener="#{regionMaster.regionList}" validateClient="false" immediate="true" />-->
                                <prime:dialog id="basicDialog" header="Basic Dialog"
                                    widgetVar="dlg1">
                                    <h:outputText value="Resistance to PrimeFaces is futile!" />
                                </prime:dialog>


                                <prime:commandButton id="basic" value="Basic"
                                    onclick="PF('dlg1').show();" type="button" />

                            </prime:column>
                        </prime:row>
                        <prime:row>
                            <prime:column>
                                <h:outputLabel for="txtRegionName"  value="RegionName" />
                            </prime:column>
                            <prime:column colspan="3">
                                <prime:inputText id="txtRegionName" value="#{regionMaster.regionName}"
                                    label="Region Name" required="true" />
                            </prime:column>
                        </prime:row>

                        <prime:row>
                            <prime:column>
                            </prime:column>
                            <prime:column colspan="1">
                                <prime:commandButton action="#{regionMaster.save}"
                                    value="save" />
                            </prime:column>
                            <prime:column colspan="1">
                                <prime:commandButton accesskey="R" alt="Click to Reset"
                                    validateClient="false" immediate="true"
                                    action="#{regionMaster.reset}" value="Reset" />
                            </prime:column>
                            <prime:column colspan="1">
                                <prime:commandButton accesskey="D"
                                    onclick="if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) return false"
                                    alt="Click to Delete" actionListener="#{regionMaster.delete}"
                                    validateClient="false" immediate="true" value="delete">
                                </prime:commandButton>
                            </prime:column>
                        </prime:row>
                    </prime:panelGrid>
                </prime:panel></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </h:form>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

MyBean is

```
package com.sst.cms.web.beans;

import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@ManagedBean(name="regionMaster",eager=false)
@SessionScoped
@Named("regionMaster")
public class RegionMasterBean implements Serializable {

    //private static final FacesMessage RegionList = null;


    public RegionMasterBean() {

    }

    private String regionId;
    private String regionName;
    private String createdBy;
    private Date createdDate;
    private String modifiedBy;
    private Date modifiedDate;
    private String entity;

    private ArrayList<RegionMasterBean> regionList;


    public String getRegionId() {
        System.out.println("Region id======"+regionId);

        return regionId;
    }
    public void setRegionId(String regionId) {
        System.out.println("Region id======"+regionId);
        this.regionId = regionId;
    }
    // other getter+setter
    public String save(){   
        System.out.println("Bean is calleddddddddd");           
        return "SUCCESSFUL";

    }

    public void reset(){
        this.regionId = "";
        this.regionName = "";
    }

    public String delete(){         
        return "Sucess";
    }


    //      public String setId(){
    //          System.out.println("Region iddddddddddddd");
    //          
    //          FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    //          this.regionId = getCountryParam(fc);
    //      
    //          return regionId;
    //      }
    //      

    public ArrayList<RegionMasterBean> regionListLoad(){            

        regionList = new ArrayList<RegionMasterBean>();

        RegionMasterBean dto = new RegionMasterBean();          
        dto.setRegionId("REG001");
        dto.setRegionName("India");         
        RegionMasterBean dto1 = new RegionMasterBean();
        dto1.setRegionId("REG002");
        dto1.setRegionName("Afganisthan");
        regionList.add(dto); 
        regionList.add(dto1);       
        return regionList;

    }



    public ArrayList<RegionMasterBean> getRegionList() {
        return regionList;
    }
    public void setRegionList(ArrayList<RegionMasterBean> regionList) {
        this.regionList = regionList;
    }





     public String saveSetting(){
         System.out.println("this is calleddddddd");
         this.regionId = "Roo1";
        return regionId;

     }

        @PostConstruct
    public void regionList() {  
        System.out.println("region list is calledddddddd");
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("RegionList");       
        System.out.println("region list is calledddddddd");
    }  



         }
```

It works fine with the project where i have jsf 1.2 but when i add this to  a new project with jsf 2.2 it shows the error

Comment: Sorry, we're going to need your xhtml and bean code to say *anything* about this.

Comment: I've never tried this, but using `@Named` and `@ManagedBean` together sounds like a receipt for disaster. Try leaving of `@Named` if you don't inject the bean anywhere, also `<head>` probably should be `<h:head>` and remove the `<ui:composition>`, it causes JSF to leave out your header.

Comment: I tried removing @Named and changed to <h:head> still the error remains the same